# Is it possible that only limited row in table view show

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose if I want to show only 6 row at a time in a view after scrolling table view again next 6 row . So How can I do this..Is it Possible or not??

Comment: make your 6 rows size according to table height so that it can show only 6 rows on screen then after scrolling it will get another rows

Comment: do you want to fetch data from server by page ?

Comment: Yes, but according to array.count fetch only 6 or 12 row then again scroll it so show next 6 or 12 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.  You can have a class be a `UIScrollViewDelegate` and that class can be notified when your user scrolls beyond the currently loaded table cells (say you load just 6 originally).  You can then pull the rest of the data and reload the `UITableView`.

You will need to do some calculations based on heights to know when your user has scrolled to that point.